# Handling threading and web requests on Windows Phone 7

Tags: multithreading, windows-phone-7

How can you make a background web request and then update the UI, but have all the code that does the web requesting/parsing in a separate class so you can use it in multiple places?  I thought I could use the classes methods as event handlers for a BackgroundWorker class, like

```
APIHelper mHelper = new APIHelper("http://example.com?foo=bar");
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
bw.DoWork +=new DoWorkEventHandler(mHelper.GetResponse);
bw.RunWorkerCompleted +=new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(mHelper.HandleResponse);
bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

where APIHelper has the method

```
public void GetResponse(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = (BackgroundWorker) sender;

    WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(this.URL);
    IAsyncResult result = (IAsyncResult)
                              request.BeginGetResponse(ResponseCallback, request);
}
```

but then I don't know how to access the worker thread from ResponseCallback and, anyway, HandleResponse gets called first (obviously).  (I tried putting in `result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();` but I get a `NotSupportedException` error.) Yet I can't work out how to make the web request call synchronously.  I'm clearly trying to go about this the wrong way, but I have no idea what the right way is.

---

**ETA:**

My aim is to be able to go:

- user clicks (a) button(s) (on various pages)
- a "working" message is displayed on the UI thread (and then input is blocked)
- in a background thread my APIHelper class makes the relevant API call, gets the response, and passes it back to the UI thread; I only seem to be able to do this by starting another thread and waiting for that to return, because there's no synchronous web requests
- the UI thread updates with the returned message (and input continues as before)

I can do the first two bits, and if I have the response, I can do the last bits, but I can't work out how to do the middle bit.  Hopefully that made it clearer!

Comment: why do you need access to the BackgroundWorker in the callback?

Comment: So I can pass the response back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me several tried before I found there is a `Dispatcher`.

During the `BackgroundWorker`'s `dowork` and `complete` methods you can call:

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
// UPDATE UI BITS
});
```

I think the `Dispatcher` is only available in the view. So I'm not sure if the methods can exist outside of the xaml.cs

Put whatever you want to update in your UI; when updating an `ObservableCollection` you must do the update of you items in the `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` too

This link might be a good read too:
http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/All-about-Splash-Screens-in-WP7-ndash-Creating-animated-Splash-Screen

**Update to assist notes**

This is just a rough idea mind you...

```
bw.DoWork +=new DoWorkEventHandler(DoWork);
bw.RunWorkerCompleted +=new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(Complete)

// At least I think the EA is DoWork....
public void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
        mHelper.GetResponse();
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
              UIObject.Visibility Collapse.
        });

        // Wait and do work with response.
    });
}

public void Complete(object sender, RunWorkerCompleteEventArgs e)
{
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
              UIObject.Visible ....
        });
}
```

Comment: I don't seem to be able to call the Dispatcher from the callback method of the asynchronous webrequest, and the BackgroundWorker's complete method finishes before the callback method runs.

Comment: I would call your APIHelper from a `dowork` method. The idea of the background worker is to do what you need to do, before continuing. If you try calling and completing the work you need to do with you APIHelper from with that you wont need to pass in the background worker to that.

Comment: Okay, that seems to make sense but how do I wait for the webresponse to come back?

Comment: Isn't there an option for a non Async GetResponse? I'll investigate tonight. You might be able to loop until the Status is successful. or have you worked something out?

Answer (score 0):

I'd put all this logic in a viewmodel that the viewmodel of each page inherits from.
Have the pages bind to properties on the viewmodel (such as `ShowLoading`, etc.) which the model updates appropriately. i.e. before making the webrequest and in the callback.

As you won't be running the viewmodel code in the UI thread you also wouldn't need to run in a separate BackgroundWorker and you'll be able to access the properties of the viewmodel without issue.

Comment: Is there a good tutorial somewhere on the View-Model-ViewModel thing?

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful if you use a helper class that I have developed for WebDownload purposes during WP7 development.

I'm using it in 2-3 WP7 apps and no problem so far. Give it a go to see if it helps. You can get the class from the my blog linked bellow:

http://www.manorey.net/mohblog/?p=17#content

[NOTE] When working with this class you don't need to run anything in a background worker or new thread; it handles it all asynchronously.